# Orthography "gha" vs. "ga" in Italian

Tags: orthography, history, spelling

I know that h is used to signal the hard g sound when i or e follows, but is there anything like this, perhaps historical, for the letter a, i.e., gha?

I ask because I've been researching Italian genealogical records and found some last names spelled alternatively with -ga or -gha sometimes even in the same document. I've seen this many times, so I'll provide an example:

If you type "gha" into the Cognome box on [this search page](http://dl.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/gallery?g2_view=search.SearchScan&g2_form[search]=name) for the Italian government genealogical records, you'll see that one of the more common names returned is Bragha. If you then type "Bragha" instead into the Cognome box the first name returned is Annonziata Bragha whose parents were Lorenzo and Lucia, as shown in the top of this image:

[image]

The first image below that shows a portion of the [source document](http://dl.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/v/Archivio+di+Stato+di+Mantova/Stato+civile+napoleonico/Casalmoro+con+Acquafredda/Morti/1806/280/004121430_02910.jpg.html) showing the parent names, with the "Bragha" spelling, as expected. I know the handwriting is poor -- that's how it is in genealogical records sometimes.

The final image at the bottom shows that in the index ([on this page](http://dl.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/v/Archivio+di+Stato+di+Mantova/Stato+civile+napoleonico/Casalmoro+con+Acquafredda/Morti/1806/280/004121430_02904.jpg.html?g2_imageViewsIndex=0)) Annonziata's last name is spelled "Braga"

I could give more examples, if needed; I just gave this one because it's the first Bragha on that search page. The point is, I've seen this many times and want to know if there's any basis in Italian for use of "h" in gha. Perhaps historically? These records are from the 1800's.

If there is not, my best guess is that the folks who made these records were barely literate and simply mistakenly applied the rule about h at times.

Here's another example with better handwriting, again with an image from the source [document on top](http://dl.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/v/Archivio+di+Stato+di+Mantova/Stato+civile+napoleonico/San+Benedetto/Morti/1806/2412/4660739_01730.jpg.html) and from the [index page below](http://dl.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/v/Archivio+di+Stato+di+Mantova/Stato+civile+napoleonico/San+Benedetto/Morti/1806/2412/4660739_01708.jpg.html?g2_imageViewsIndex=0), and both with links so you can check where I got those screenshots if you like. Notice here that even the father/child last names are spelled differently.
[image]

Comment: On the first image I read "figlia di Lorenzo e di Lucia..." (daughter of Lorenzo and Lucia) and in both cases the "a" has a curl at the end, as opposite to the last word that you wrote as Bragha but it could maybe be "Braghe"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi I added another example because the handwriting was so poor in the first one. Please trust me, this happens a lot in these genealogical records -- I hope someone can address the substance of my question.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: In fact, if you use [Dizionario storico dell'italiano antico](http://tlio.ovi.cnr.it/TLIO/) and you search forms that contain the string "gha"  (Ricerche avanzate --> Forme --> Espansa), you will find lots of them. These are words from the XIV century, but it seems plausible to me that this orthography survived in some proper names for some centuries.

Comment: @Charo Thanks for providing enough info so I could reproduce your search. However, to be honest, I'm no linguist and don't really understand what all this means. It's seems relevant to my question and so I'd appreciate if you could expand on what it means when you use this tool this way. Perhaps you could develop this as answer rather than just a comment, with more examples. It might be the closest I get to an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM:   This is a database of words present in Italian texts until the end of the XIV century. It's still under construction (not all words are present nowadays). I simply wanted to show that there was a time in which this orthography was common.

Comment: This [article from Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ortografia_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) explains how Pietro Bembo (XVI century) tried to impose some ortographic rules, but that such rules were not always followed: "i modelli indicati da Bembo sono indiscussi per quanto riguarda la forma linguistica, ma non per quanto riguarda la grafia". One of these rules is "l’abolizione dei nessi ‹ch/gh› + ‹a›, ‹o›".

Comment: Thanks for following up, @Charo. I did my best to read the link. If I understand correctly, the implication is that there was indeed a practice of "gh" being joined to "a" as in "gha" -- but that Bembo tried to stop this practice with his orthographic rules. That would answer my question. Since most of the time the different spellings are between the index and the main document, it's possible that these 2 sections were made by different writers, one of whom had a better grasp of the rule than the other.

Comment: @TonyM:   My hypothesis is that what happened to people who wrote these documents is something which is quite common nowadays with Catalan surnames: some of them are written in a way that violates current Catalan orthographical rules and this often leads to confusion. For instance, my husband surname is Comellas, which actually is the plural of "comella". According to current orthographical rules, such plural must be spelled "comelles" and, for this reason, lots of people erroneously write my husband surname Comelles (Comellas and Comelles are identically pronounced in my variety of Catalan).

Comment: Also in the book *Italiano*, speaking about what happens before *e* and *i*, Serianni says: "dopo molte oscillazioni nella grafia dei primi secoli, *c* e *g* si stabilizzarono per le palatali e i digrammi *ch* and *gh* per le velari". I think that, at the beginning of the XIX century, the stabilization of this aspect of orthography was already been accomplished, but if this surname has survived in the form "Bragha", this orthographic rule might be the source of confusion to the people who wrote these documents.